# Uneven partition assignment in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I am experiencing strange assignment behavior with Kafka Streams. I am having 3-node cluster of Kafka streams. My stream is pretty straightforward, one source topic (24 partitions, all kafka brokers are running on other machines than kafka stream nodes) and our stream graph only takes messages, group them by key, perform some filtering and store everything to sink topic. Everything is running with 2 Kafka Threads on each node.

However whenever I am doing rolling update of my kafka stream (by shutting down always only one app so other two nodes are running) my kafka streams ends with uneven number of partitions per "node"(usually 16-9-0). Only once I restart node01 and sometimes node02 cluster gets back to more even state.

**Can somebody advice any hint how I can achieve more equal distribution before additional restarts?**

Answer (score 0):

I assume both nodes running the kafka streams app have identical group ids for consumption.

I suggest you check to see if the partition assignment strategy your consumers are using isn't `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor`.

If this is the case, configure it to be `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor`. This way, when the group coordinator receives a JoinGroup request and hands the partitions over to the group leader, the group leader will ensure the spread between the nodes isn't uneven by more than 1.

Unless you're using an older version of Kafka streams, the default is Range and does not guarantee even spread across consumers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Kafka 2.6. I have checked the code and kafka streams are not using any of those assignors but StreamsPartitionAssignor

Answer (score 0):

Is your Kafka Streams application stateful? If so, you can possibly thank this well-intentioned KIP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-441%3A+Smooth+Scaling+Out+for+Kafka+Streams

If you want to override this behaviour, you can set `acceptable.recovery.lag=9223372036854775807` (Long.MAX_VALUE).

The definition of that config from https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#acceptable-recovery-lag

> The maximum acceptable lag (total number of offsets to catch up from the changelog) for an instance to be considered caught-up and able to receive an active task. Streams only assigns stateful active tasks to instances whose state stores are within the acceptable recovery lag, if any exist, and assigns warmup replicas to restore state in the background for instances that are not yet caught up. Should correspond to a recovery time of well under a minute for a given workload. Must be at least 0.